# Does elimination imply projection of symmetry?

Tags: lie-groups, differential-equations

Let suppose we have system of ODE (linear for simplicity) for two unknown functions $x(t), y(t)$
$$
x''(t) = a(t) x'(t) + b(t) y'(t) + c(t) x(t) + d(t) y(t),
$$
and
$$
y''(t) = e(t) x'(t) + g(t) y'(t) + h(t) x(t) + f(t) y(t),
$$
which admits some Lie symmetry group.

We can also eliminate one unknown function by means of differential elimination.
The new (higher order) equation, let say for $x(t)$, will also admit some symmetries.
Are there any well-known connections between them? Like projection of symmetry group?